# Problemas com fórmulas para extrair textos com espaços diferentes

Tags: microsoft-excel

Pretendo extrair apenas as numerações em vermelho para a tabela seguinte "Red", porém os espaços estão diferente e eu já testei um monte de fórmulas para resolver essa questão.

Utilizei uma fórmula um pouco complexa, mas ela não deu certo, tudo isso por causa que os espaços entre os números vermelhos são diferente, eu utilizei essa fórmula:

`=ARRUMAR(DIREITA(ESQUERDA(SUBSTITUIR(ARRUMAR(A207);" ";REPT(" ";10));30);50))`

Como eu faço para extrair apenas as numerações em vermelho??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas qual é a lógica para saber que número precisa extrair, seria o que segue uma sequência sem repetir?

Comment: Estou no trabalho e aqui estou sem tempo, mas você pode fazer com VBA utilizando a função MID mesclada com esse código aqui https://superuser.com/questions/1067320/check-excel-cell-if-font-is-a-certain-color

Comment: Eu queria apenas os números em vermelho de acordo com cada células referente. No caso tem uns que são repetidos, mas caso eu altere para outro tipo de numeração, eles tem que ficarem organizados de acordo com a posição e a quantidade

Comment: @ Max sei pouquíssimo de VBA, mas sei editar códigos e gravar macros. Eu posso esperar, caso você queira preparar um código ou uma fórmula mesmo no Excel

Comment: através de fórmula é impossível

Comment: O que deseja extrair está formatado como vermelho ou você apenas colocou como vermelho para indicar o que deseja extrair?

Comment: @anonimo Eu apenas pintei em vermelho para indicar o que eu quero extrair

Comment: Veja se a lógica é a seguinte: eliminar o eventual 11 se ocorrer no início da string e depois pegar tudo a partir da primeira ocorrência de 1 até o espaço que o segue.

Comment: @anonimo Essa fórmula que eu postei ela faz quase isso, mas os número tem que estar um em baixo do outro não importa a quantidade e ela funciona nesse caso! Mas quando os números se encontram de forma separadas, não da certo!

Comment: Se desse para utilizar essa mesma fórmula e incrementar algo mais, seria bom! Mas o outro usuário acima disse que era impossível com fórmulas, seria possível somente se utilizar VBA

Comment: Sinceramente: não entendi o que tal fórmula faz. Para mim é sem sentido.

Comment: @anonimo A fórmula extrair valores em sequencia com os valores das linhas, que vem depois, testa ela e altere as numerações "10,30,50" para regular o que você deseja exibir na extração de algum texto, nome, sobrenome, referencias de algum produto etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

Insira o código abaixo em um módulo. Alt + F11, Insert, Module.

```
Function ExtrairTextoPorCor(pRange As Range) As String

        Dim xOut As String
        Dim xValue As String
        Dim i As Long
        xValue = pRange.Text

        For i = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
    'O RGB determina a cor que a fonte está, caso esteja diferente, faça a alteração no trecho do código RGB(255,0,0)
            If pRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                xOut = xOut & VBA.Mid(xValue, i, 1)
            End If

        Next

        ExtrairTextoPorCor = xOut
    End Function
```

Volte para a planilha e procure uma célula vazia e insira a fórmula =ExtrairTextoPorCor(A207)

Comment: conseguiu aplicar a solução?

Comment: Sim, deu certo! Só uma coisinha que incomoda um pouco é que, se tiver por exemplo duas numerações com cores iguais, ex: 111 00 111, vamos supor que estes dois "111" está em vermelho, nesse caso ele vai extrair dessa forma: "111111" sem dar o espaço entre eles. Porém se formatar os espaçamento em vermelho ele obedece e extrai o espaço, "111 111"

Comment: Utilize esse código

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ExtrairTextoPorCor(pRange As Range) As String

        Dim xOut As String
        Dim xValue As String
        Dim i As Long
        xValue = pRange.Text

        For i = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
    'O RGB determina a cor que a fonte está, caso esteja diferente, faça a alteração no trecho do código RGB(255,0,0)
            If pRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                xOut = xOut & VBA.Mid(xValue, i, 1)
            ElseIf pRange.Characters(i, 1).Text = " " Then
                xOut = xOut & VBA.Mid(xValue, i, 1)
            End If
        Next
        ExtrairTextoPorCor = xOut
End Function
```